# Xbrl Validation

Tags: xsd-validation, xbrl

I have a generated `XDocument` that needs to be validated to `Xbrl xsd's`
I have created a custom `XmlResolver` to load all the `xsd` files from the external party.

This is the `GetEntity` Function from my resolver so i can get the included `xsd's`:

```
Public Overrides Function GetEntity(absoluteUri As Uri, role As String, ofObjectToReturn As Type) As Object

    'If absoluteUri.ToString.Contains("www.xbrl.org") Then
    '    Nothing here yet
    'End If

    Dim nmSpace As String = _assembly.GetName.Name.ToString
    Dim resource = String.Concat(nmSpace, ".", Path.GetFileName(absoluteUri.ToString()))
    Dim result = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource)

    Return result
End Function
```

However there are a lot of xsd's from the xbrl namespace and they don't get loaded.

I started downloading them to include them as a resource but there are just to many files so it doesn't seem like the best solution.

I hope anyone has some experience in validating an Xbrl file because i feel like i'm missing the point here :)

Comment: If this is .NET (not WinRT) code, then you might take a look at Gepsio (Gepsio.codeplex.com) to see if Gepsio can validate your document automatically.

Answer (score 2):

www.Arelle.org

This open source project contains a web-service that can be used to validate Xbrl files.
This what i implemented right now and it checks against all the required Xbrl rules

Comment: Yes, besides desktop application, Arelle provides local web service that runs in your local machine. It has other useful restful services as well e.g. localhost:8080/help gives the list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using plain Xml-Xsd validation and this seems ok so far.

I implemented the custom resolver like this:

```
Public Class ResourceXmlResolver
Inherits XmlResolver

Private Shared _xmlUrlResolver As XmlUrlResolver = New XmlUrlResolver()
Private _assembly As Assembly

Public Sub New(assembly As Assembly)
    _assembly = assembly
End Sub

Public Overrides Function GetEntity(absoluteUri As Uri, role As String, ofObjectToReturn As Type) As Object

    If absoluteUri.ToString.Contains("www.xbrl.org") Then
        Return _xmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(absoluteUri, role, ofObjectToReturn)
    End If

    Dim nmSpace As String = _assembly.GetName.Name.ToString
    Dim resource = String.Concat(nmSpace, ".", Path.GetFileName(absoluteUri.ToString()))
    Dim result = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource)

    Return result
End Function
Public Overrides WriteOnly Property Credentials() As System.Net.ICredentials
    Set(value As System.Net.ICredentials)
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

The Xsd files provided by the third party are embedded resources.

I set the Assembly to the assembly containing my Xsd files, so when the GetEntity method is called by setting the resolver:

```
Dim schemas As XmlSchemaSet = New XmlSchemaSet()
    schemas.XmlResolver = New ResourceXmlResolver(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly)
```

They are loaded correctly. I do however provide a check for the xsd's from www.xbrl.org.
In that case i'm using the standard XmlUrlResolver to get them from the web.

I also got this working by just downloading all the xbrl xsd's and also embedding them.

I hope this is enough validation for Xbrl but got this working so far :)